# Finding percentage between columns in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this SQL code I wrote in Oracle:

```
   SELECT DISTINCT 
          O.shipcountry, S.companyname,
          O.orderid,
          TO_CHAR(O.freight, '$999,999.999'), 
          TO_CHAR(sum(unitprice)*count(quantity), '$999,999.99') as "Order Total"
     FROM corp.Order_Details D
LEFT JOIN corp.Orders O ON D.orderid = O.orderid)
LEFT JOIN corp.Shippers S ON O.shipvia = S.Shipperid
    WHERE O.freight >= '500'
 GROUP BY O.shipcountry, S.companyname, O.orderid, to_char(O.freight, '$999,999.999');
```

This basically gives me an orderid, country it was shipped to, shipper name, order total and the total amount of freight that was charged.

### Question

Without making this too complicated, does anyone know how I could write in the percent of freight (freight/order total)?  I tried to put it in but it says that it cannot be grouped because of the sum in the order total.

Comment: You appear to have a stray close parens at the end of the first LEFT JOIN line.  And your price calculation is rather weird - shouldn't that be more like `SUM(D.unitprice * D.quantity)`.  Adding all the prices, and then multiplying that by the number of order lines seems a little, errr, eccentric?  Consider 1000 paperclips at £0.01 and 1 diamond at £1000.00; you'd be calculating a cost of £2000.02, instead of £1010.00.

Answer (score 1):

So...

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
       O.shipcountry, 
       S.companyname, 
       O.orderid,
       TO_CHAR(O.freight, '$999,999.999'), 
       TO_CHAR(SUM(unitprice) * COUNT(quantity), '$999,999.99') as "Order Total", 
       O.freight / (SUM(unitprice) * COUNT(quantity)) as "Percent"
   ...
```

...doesn't work?

Comment: It might work if the basic calculation was sane...and if you multiplied the value by 100.  The problem in the basic calculation derives from the question - the missing 100 is your issue.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you mean that you added something like `O.freight / (SUM(unitprice) * COUNT(quantity))` and got `ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression` as a result.

The reason for this is that `O.freight` is not one of your GROUP BY expressions -- you are grouping by `to_char(O.freight, '$999,999.999')`.  You should be able to group by the column value alone and have it work.

```
  SELECT DISTINCT 
          O.shipcountry, S.companyname,
          O.orderid,
          TO_CHAR(O.freight, '$999,999.999'), 
          TO_CHAR(sum(unitprice)*count(quantity), '$999,999.99') as "Order Total",
          O.freight / (SUM(unitprice) * COUNT(quantity)) as "Percent"
     FROM corp.Order_Details D
LEFT JOIN corp.Orders O ON D.orderid = O.orderid)
LEFT JOIN corp.Shippers S ON O.shipvia = S.Shipperid
    WHERE O.freight >= '500'
 GROUP BY O.shipcountry, S.companyname, O.orderid, O.freight;
```

I suspect it is a common misconception that the expressions in the GROUP BY clause must exactly match the ungrouped expressions in the SELECT clause.  It is sufficient to group by the actual values -- you can still apply functions to them in the selection.